# CSS suggestion max-right or workaround?

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, stylesheet

Are there plans to add this to CSS?

```
min-right:10% ;
max-bottom:100px ; ...
```

something like

```
<div style="min-left:1000px; min-right:10%; max-left:1200px; 
            position:fixed" ></div>
```

Is there any workaround to apply today?  Answers may include javascript, jquery plugins, etc.

For some background:

Our fixed div in the example above will at 1280 window-width be starting at 10% / 128px from the right, but not starting earlier than 1000px from the left,  thus being at most 152 pixel wide, limited by the horizontal positions 1000px and 1152px with equal gap to those marks if that div is within another with a centered align. - If instead you try `<div style=”right:10%;left;1000px; max-width: calc(90%-1000); position:fixed`, not the same will happend but the max-width will be forced always and our div will be forced to be be both: 1000px from left and 10% from right even when it's content actually "wants" just way fewer pixels width...

And to explain why now also `max-left:1200px` is necessary: If the window's width will be greater, for example 1600px, then of course again the min. gap to the right end of the windows will be 10% / 160 Pixel and to the left 1000 so the max-width of the the div will result in 440px but what if it only has 100px today? Then we additionally want to make sure it starts somewhere between 1000 and 1200 from the left and not only 10% from the right, even if the inherited align should be ‘centered or ‘right and the div just including 10px of content that shall not result in it to be in 1235px distant from the left or even 1430px but not at most 1200px.

Comment: My previous edit removed the 'keywords' from the title, because they serve no purpose (other than to obfuscate the question you're trying to ask). If you need to tag your question, use the tags sensibly ([tag:css] and [tag:css3] serve no different purpose, and there's nothing in your question that requires one over the other. Similarly the [tag:stylesheet] and its (*near*) duplicate [tag:alternate-stylesheet] serve no purpose; pick *one* and add other subjects there). The only thing that should be in the title is the question-title itself, not meta-information.

Comment: If the root of your problem is down to the width of the browser window, you could try using media queries to apply different CSS for different sizes of window.

Comment: David was correct in his edit. Keywords don't belong in titles here, so I've removed them and cleaned up a bit of the formatting in the body of your question.

Comment: Please stop adding "keywords" in your title after them repeatedly being removed by various people. (this post was automatically flagged for so many edits)

Answer (score 5):

1. **Don't** use absolute positioning except if your level in CSS is advanced. Recipe for disaster and content covering other content.

   - Learn about now usable values of display like `inline-block` and `table-cell`
   - Learn about float of course, and `clear` property
   - Learn about what a *clearfix* is and the difference with the property `clear`. [Implementation of clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)
   - `clip()` can be used, only on absolutely positioned elements so it's relevant here
2. Learn about a cool trick with [absolute positioning (the bonus tip part)](http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/).
3. Learn about `min-width`, `max-width`, `min-height` and `max-height`.

   - `min-height` is useful when a background image should never be cropped even without enough content
   - `max-width` and `min-width` are useful for fluid layouts, being responsive without the need of media queries and breakpoints, widths in `em`s, etc
4. background images can now be controlled with CSS3: `background-size`, etc See [E. Weil 'standardista' website](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties)

There are no plans of adding the properties you mentioned, though there's a `calc()` value that may help you. See [MDN calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) (and caniuse.com for compatibility...)

Answer (score 0):

Okay! suppose you have a div width of 400 pixels.

```
+----------------------+
|                      | <div id="main">
+----------------------+
```

And you want to give a min-left 50px inside this div a new div width of 300 pixels.

```
+----------------------+
|   +------+           |
|   |      |           | <div id="left">
|   +------+           |
+----------------------+
```

What if you want this div max-left 100px. This would go like this.

```
+----------------------+
|       +------+       |
|       |      |       | <div id="left">
|       +------+       |
+----------------------+
```

> And what if you apply **margin: 0 auto;** to this div. This would really manage the contents exactly as want, yes/no: **no**. When you give **margin: 0 100px;** or something like this would manage as want, yes/no: **yes**. So, like the way we do in css everything is written in deep thinking and it's not needed to give min-left or something like you. And there are a lot of tricks to do the way you want.